# Angular highlightjs I can not make the css value appears without the single quote

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I can not make the css value appears without the single quote:

```html
<div id="editor" hljs ource="code" include="'compile-me'" compile="true" language="css"  ></div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="compile-me">
#item {
    width: '{{value + unit}}';
    height: '{{value + unit}}';
}
</script>
```

display

```css
#item {
    width: '200px';
    height: '200px';
}
```

when should appear as follows, without the quotes

```css
#item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

the truth, I'm new with angular and I am really impressed with this issue, because with jQuery already have solved ....

Comment: Just remove quotes: `width: {{value + unit}}`. You don't need them.

Comment: fails, the variables appear in the code

Comment: have you tried `width: {{value}} + '{{unit}}'`?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YnK4A8YKOInbpLR7Okip?p=preview

Comment: fails, only interprets angular variables from the single quote

Comment: Ok,  thanks dsfq, but now no color code